# Populate an array each time a click is done on an element with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have several items like this:

```
<div data-category="fruit" data-value="apple" data-color="yellow">Apple</div>
<div data-category="fruit" data-value="apple" data-color="green">Apple</div>
<div data-category="fruit" data-value="cherry" data-color="red">Cherry</div>
<div data-category="vegetable" data-value="tomato" data-color="red">Tomato</div>
<div data-category="vegetable" data-value="carrot" data-color="orange">Carrot</div>
```

Each time the user clicks on an element, I should store `data-*` informations into an array.

It possible that a user can clicks multiple times of the same items but with a different colour (i. e. : Apple). In this case, I should update the array with the last clicked item values and remove the old one.

The desired output is for example something like this:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [category] => fruit
        [value] => apple
        [color] => green
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [category] => vegetable
        [value] => tomato
        [color] => red
    )
)
```

Please, note that in this example, the user clicks on the first and after on the second `<div>`. That's why, I should have only the second `<div>` info and not the infos from the first one `<div>`.

Let me know if it's clear.

Actually, here the code I have:

```
var arr = {};
arr[$(this).data('value') + '_' + $(this).data('color')] = { 
    "category": $(this).data('category'),
    "value": $(this).data('value'),
    "color": $(this).data('color')
};
```

The problem with this code is I can't really use it after as I makes an invalid array.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Please add your javascript code

Comment: @TamilSelvanC, I added some code.

Comment: Your main structure is an object, not an array... Just use the `values` as the properties of the object for an easy update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this .Filter with `data-value` and `data-category` based .IF you need more add condition with in filter

> Note: `Js array not like php associative array its called object in js`. Array not have key value pair .SO use with object instead of array

1.Before Object push, filter the array with same value not exist

```js
var arr=[];
$(document).on('click','div[data-category]',function(){
   arr =arr.filter(a=> a.value != $(this).data('value') && a.category != $(this).data('category'))
   arr.push({
     category:$(this).data('category'),
     value   :$(this).data('value'),
     color   :$(this).data('color')
   });
   
   console.log(arr)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-category="fruit" data-value="apple" data-color="yellow">Apple</div>
<div data-category="fruit" data-value="apple" data-color="green">Apple</div>
<div data-category="fruit" data-value="cherry" data-color="red">Cherry</div>
<div data-category="vegetable" data-value="tomato" data-color="red">Tomato</div>
<div data-category="vegetable" data-value="carrot" data-color="orange">Carrot</div>
```

Comment: Hello Prasanth, if I click on the second element, it keeps the infos from the first element.

Comment: check the console.Each time click previous same value object are removed in  array.

Comment: Can I pass this object to a PHP page like a json?

Comment: ya sure.in php the object will like your result(associative array)

Answer (score 0):

Get the data of item clicked using `dataset` and then use `findIndex()` to check if the item with same `value` is present.

```js
let arr = [];
let divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
divs.forEach(div => {
  div.addEventListener('click',(e) => {
    let data = e.target.dataset;
    let ind = arr.findIndex(x => data.value === x.value);
    if(ind === -1) arr.push(data);
    else arr[ind] = data;
    console.log(arr)
  })
  
})
```

```html
<div data-category="fruit" data-value="apple" data-color="yellow">Apple</div>
<div data-category="fruit" data-value="apple" data-color="green">Apple</div>
<div data-category="fruit" data-value="cherry" data-color="red">Cherry</div>
<div data-category="vegetable" data-value="tomato" data-color="red">Tomato</div>
<div data-category="vegetable" data-value="carrot" data-color="orange">Carrot</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var result = [];
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("div")).forEach(link => link.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  let category_name = this.getAttribute('data-category');
  let category_value = this.getAttribute('data-value');
  let category_color = this.getAttribute('data-color');

  var found = result.some(function(el) {
    return el.category_name === category_name && el.category_value === category_value;
  });
  if (!found) {
    result.push({
      category_name: category_name,
      category_value: category_value,
      category_color: category_color
    });
  } else {
    index = result.findIndex(x => x.category_name == category_name && x.category_value == category_value);
    result[index]['category_color'] = category_color;

  }

  console.log(result);
}))
```

```html
<div data-category="fruit" data-value="apple" data-color="yellow">Apple</div>
<div data-category="fruit" data-value="apple" data-color="green">Apple</div>
<div data-category="fruit" data-value="cherry" data-color="red">Cherry</div>
<div data-category="vegetable" data-value="tomato" data-color="red">Tomato</div>
<div data-category="vegetable" data-value="carrot" data-color="orange">Carrot</div>
```